# WSO2 Carbon SSO Setup

Tags: security, ssl, single-sign-on, wso2

I'm getting in touch with all this security stuff and I am stuck configuring the SSO with WSO2 Carbon Server and the company software (CS).

I've setup WSO2 with my own keystore and truststore which has the self signed certificate of the client, the Response Signing and Assertion Encryption are enabled

I've build a metadaIDP XML file with the WSO2 Server Samlsso URL and the client certificate.

I have attached to the CS's the client keystore and the IDPmetadata.xml to communicate with WSO2 server.

When I put my login credentials to access the application, the WSO2 post to a set callback URL the authentication allowing the login with the client certificate attached, but the company software see it as non trusted, and they start a infinite loop of authentication request - response.

Any ideas or help please??

**IDP Metadata File:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<md:EntitiesDescriptor Name="urn:mace:shibboleth:testshib:two" xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" >
    <md:EntityDescriptor entityID="https://localhost:9443/samlsso">
        <md:IDPSSODescriptor WantAuthnRequestsSigned="true"
                             protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:protocol urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
            <md:KeyDescriptor use="signing">
                <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#&quot;&gt;">
                    <ds:X509Data>
                        <ds:X509Certificate>
                            <ServerCertificate>
                        </ds:X509Certificate>
                    </ds:X509Data>
                </ds:KeyInfo>
            </md:KeyDescriptor>
            <md:KeyDescriptor use="encryption">
                <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#&quot;&gt;">
                    <ds:X509Data>
                        <ds:X509Certificate>
                          <Server.certificate>
                        </ds:X509Certificate>
                    </ds:X509Data>
                </ds:KeyInfo>
            </md:KeyDescriptor>
            <md:KeyDescriptor>
                <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#&quot;&gt;">
                    <ds:X509Data>
                        <ds:X509Certificate>
                          <ServerCertificate>
                        </ds:X509Certificate>
                    </ds:X509Data>
                </ds:KeyInfo>
            </md:KeyDescriptor>
            <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient</md:NameIDFormat>
            <md:SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:mace:shibboleth:1.0:profiles:AuthnRequest"
                                 Location="https://localhost:9443/samlsso" />
            <md:SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"
                                 Location="https://localhost:9443/samlsso" />
            <md:SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect"
                                 Location="https://localhost:9443/samlsso" />
        </md:IDPSSODescriptor>
        <md:Organization>
            <md:OrganizationName xml:lang="en">Docucom AG</md:OrganizationName>
            <md:OrganizationDisplayName xml:lang="en">Docucom AG</md:OrganizationDisplayName>
            <md:OrganizationURL xml:lang="en">http://www.docucom.ch</md:OrganizationURL>
        </md:Organization>
        <md:ContactPerson contactType="technical">
            <md:GivenName>Its</md:GivenName>
            <md:SurName>Me</md:SurName>
            <md:EmailAddress>its.me@docucom.ch</md:EmailAddress>
        </md:ContactPerson>
    </md:EntityDescriptor>
</md:EntitiesDescriptor>
```

**CS SSO Connection Class:**

```
private Client createSAML2Client(AuthenticationDTO authentication)
        throws ServiceBeanException, GeneralSecurityException {

    if(authentication.getKeyStore() == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException(TM.encode("Error.null.s", "App.key.store"));
    }

    AccessKeyStore keyStore = accessKeyDTOService.getAccessKeyStore(authentication.getKeyStore().getName());
    if(keyStore == null) {
        throw new KeyException(TM.encode("Error.record.s.not.found.in.s",
                authentication.getKeyStore().getName(), "App.access.keys"));
    }

    SAML2ClientConfiguration saml2Configuration = new SAML2ClientConfiguration(
            ":" + keyStore.getKeyFile().getAbsolutePath(),
            new String(keyStore.getKeyFilePassword()), new String(keyStore.getKeyPassword()),
            ":" + authentication.getIdpMetadataFileName());

    saml2Configuration.setServiceProviderEntityId(authentication.getEntityId());
    saml2Configuration.setWantsAssertionsSigned(authentication.getAssertionsSigned());
    saml2Configuration.setServiceProviderMetadataPath("resource:temp-sp-metadata.xml");
    saml2Configuration.setMaximumAuthenticationLifetime(authentication.getLifetime().intValue());

    SAML2Client saml2Client = new SAML2Client(saml2Configuration);
    saml2Client.setName(authentication.getDomainName());

    return saml2Client;
}
```

Comment: You'll need to show the code!  Alternatively, if this is a question about setting up a server, it's off-topic for Stack Overflow - see [help/on-topic].

Comment: share your code or xml config for SSO in your CS